# Undo a git stash, git pull

Tags: git

I see similar questions here on stack but as far as I can tell I do not think they address my exact situation (correct me if I am wrong).

I accidentally overwrote a substantial amount of code by doing a git stash, git pull.  I ran these commands in a subdirectory within the project that a coworker was adding code to and my intent was to pull only those changes.  However, it pulled an older version of the subdirectory I was developing in as well and now I've lost at least a day or maybe more of work.

My question: is there a way to revert to my local files?  I had not committed my changes so there is no other record of that work other then what was on my local machine.

Comment: You stashed your changes? Then simply re-apply the stash to get the changes again? Of course back up your local repo before doing any further operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read your question correctly, you did a `git stash` before doing the questionable `git pull`.  When you stash, Git creates 2 (sometimes 3) commits to cover the changes to both your working directory and stage.  A stash is a sort of complete snapshot in this sense.

When you did the pull, assuming you did not rebase but did a merge, there should be a new single merge commit on top of your branch.  You can verify this by typing `git log` and inspecting.

I propose nuking that bad commit, and then just applying your stash, to get you back to where you were:

```
git checkout yourBranch    # assuming this happened on yourBranch
git reset --hard HEAD~1
git stash apply
```

This should leave you on the original commit, with both your working directory and stage also in the state they were.

Comment: In my panic I also asked a colleague who advised to simply `git stash apply` which worked.  I think this is a better answer though.

Comment: @Sledge Well you can of course apply at any point, but if you didn't really intend to do that pull, then you also have an additonal problem of _where_ (i.e. at which commit) to apply the stash.